# Unable to print the json response on client side html

Tags: jquery, node.js, json, ajax

I am using ajax to retrieve data from backend. I have a mysql table. I want to print employee name to the client side HTML. Inside the ajax request, I am getting a JSON object as response, but I am unable to print the data from the request and insert it into the html tag. I want to print employee name inside `<div>` container.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  url: 'http://localhost:3000/endpoint',                        
  success: function(response) {
    console.log('success');
    console.log(response.data[0].empid);
    $('#container').html("<h1>"+response.data[0].empname+"</h1>");
  }
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="select_div"><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submitbut" /></div> 
  <div class="container"></div>   
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're selecting an element with an *id* of "container" when you do `$('#container')`, but there's no such element. Instead, your container has a *class* of `container`. So either select the container by its class with `$('.container')` or give it an ID of `container` in the HTML.

Comment: Sorry, that was a silly mistake from my side!I observed it later

Answer (score -1):

```
 $('#container').html("<h1>"+response.data[0].empname+"</h1>");
```

The above code could be replaced with the following lines of code

```
var header = document.createElement("h1");
header.innerHTML = response.data[0].empname;
document.getElementById("#container").appendChild(header);
```

Comment: What he put there is perfectly valid jQuery; no need to switch to vanilla JS since he's clearly using jQuery already by the look of his AJAX call. That's also not how you use `getElementById` -- it wouldn't use a # at the start.